# get height of a content view subview in a scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to understand how scroll views works with autolayout.
I have understood that there are 2 ways of getting it to work, the pure version or the mixed version. I'm trying the mixed version, following the recepi on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

I have a scroll view with a contentView as the first subview. According to the apple recepi i need to do this:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGMakeSize(contentWidth,contentHeight)];
```

I have set my contentView to be 600 pt high, but when i run the app it just logs the screen size and not the actual size of the contentView.

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollViewContent.bounds.size));
```

This logs {320, 568}

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: scrollViewContent means scrollview?

Comment: scrollViewContent (UIView) is the first subview of my scrollview. The scrollViewContent holds other views like buttons and so on.

Comment: that means your scrollview have one subview(scrollViewContent). But otherview all are subview of scrollViewContent. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, the view hierarchy as below. Concept behind this, even if you change content size of your scroll view, it won't change size of all subviews.

```
---ScrollView
    -----scrollViewContent
          ------OtherViews
```

If you want to change size of content view according to content size, just change size too for content view frame.

```
CGRect newFrame = self.scrollViewContent.frame;
frame.size = scrollView.contentSize;
self.scrollViewContent.frame = newFrame;
```